# Increasing the amount of value a Select List can hold

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

I have a select list, in Oracle Apex, that i'm designing to hold the name of countries. However, the list maxes out at 180. Even though it collects the other entries, it continues to show an error until you remove the excess values.

Any idea how to increase the size?

I have 3 Country fields that need to have the same countries.

Comment: Switch to Popup LoV.